# El lanzador de aplicacion .desktop no funciona

Tags: python, linux, sh

Tengo una aplicacion hecha en python para correr en Ubuntu 18.04
Cree un script sh para en /bin para ejecutarla desde la consola con un solo comando.
Ahora quiero crear un icono para el escritorio o el panel de aplicaciones y cuando le doy click aparece unos segundos el icono en el panel pero no ejecuta nada y despues desaparece.

para crear el icono hice un app.desktop en /usr/share/applications, y adentro

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=app.sh (tambien probe poner el sh en otra ubicacion)
Icon=/home/user/app.png
Terminal=false
```

Comment: agrega por favor los permisos que tiene app.sh

Answer (score 0):

agrega permisos de ejecución al script.
puedes hacer esto con el comando

```
chmod +x app.sh
```